# What is the use of !! in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to understand what is the real use of !! in JavaScript. I tried with few different validations to understand the purpose of !!. But all tries resulted in same output.

```
var a; // undefined
if (a) {
    console.log('1');
} else {
    console.log('2');
}

if (!!a) {
    console.log('1');
} else {
    console.log('2');
}
```

For all the following scenario, I get only 2 printed in console.
    a = null;
    a = '';

Could anyone please explain this in detail?

Comment: It convert the type to `Boolean` type

Comment: You're just applying the ! operator twice. This will convert any variable to a boolean.

Comment: @Ankit, ShamPooSham Thanks for your answers. I understand the point. Assume this scenario, 
    var a = 2;
     console.log(a); ----> returns 2
     console.log(!a); -----> returns false
     console.log(!!a); ------> return true
so what is the real point in using this !!

Comment: @Rajan That information is in the duplicate which is linked at the top of your question.